# MoneroX wallet! Trouble with connecthion

Tags: monerox

I have downloaded client MoneroX, generated address, and send XMR to my Monero address. Now, I can't see XMR on my wallet because MoneroX can't connect with network. What am I doing wrong?

Screenshot: http://prnt.sc/f2ss6h

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MoneroX](https://github.com/kripod/MoneroGui.Net/releases) is deprecated and does not work properly with the latest versions of Monero. Please use a different wallet to use Monero.

If you want a desktop graphical interface, please use the official GUI, in beta 2 as I am making this post. You can download it from the [official Monero website here](https://getmonero.org/2017/03/29/monero-gui-beta-2-released.html).

Of course, you can also use the CLI interface [available here](https://getmonero.org/downloads/) or a web wallet such as [MyMonero](https://mymonero.com/). Web wallets are typically less secure than desktop wallets.

To access your Monero from another wallet, please write down your mnemonic seed from MoneroX. You can use these words to restore your account on any other wallet software. In the GUI linked above, it will give you the option to restore your account from mnemonic seed. Select this option ([full instructions here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/3876/42)).

In the CLI, you can follow the steps shown on [this page](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/user-guides/restore_account) ([full instructions here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/3876/42)).

If using MyMonero, you will need to pay an import fee ([full instructions here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/3876/42)).

Comment: It's means that i can't see my XMR? :D

Comment: And i can't spend this forever?

Comment: @Roman You can't use it in this application, but you can access your XMR from another wallet. I have updated my answer to provide links showing how to do this.

Comment: Ok. I can connected to my wallet. Thank you. I can see XMR when all blocks was downloaded? http://prnt.sc/f2v9ra

Comment: @Roman all looks good. When the bottom left shows "Synchronized", the balance will show up if you have any.