# Help needed after best friends death to retrieve wallet

Tags: wallet-recovery

Hello hopefully can help me and my friends mum out.
My best friend past away suddenly just before christmas and i have started to sort out his affairs for his mum who is 80 years old. I know he has got a monero wallet. We have his mnemonic word but not his password there is a file on his computer called wallets inside are flies with his name on and one with his name and keys.sorry but i haven't got a clue what to do to get access to the wallet. i can provide a death certificate etc.
please help

Comment: Since anyone with the word list can recover the monero, make sure you keep it secret until you've transfered any monero in that wallet, since it bypasses any password.

Answer (score 2):

You can recover a wallet with just the mnemonic seed. This should help: [How can I recover a wallet using the mnemonic seed?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10/how-can-i-recover-a-wallet-using-the-mnemonic-seed)

Comment: The official guide is easy to follow and comprehensive: https://www.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/restore_account.html

Comment: Thanks the mnemonic word is not recognised any more when try to log into the wallet any more help would be of great help

Comment: How many words is the mnemonic seed comprised of?